# qemu-system-x86_64 quit unepectedly; the emulator process for AVD was killed. Android studio error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, avd-manager

I tried the solutions already given on stackoverflow but nothing worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Change/Update the configuration(RAM or graphics settings) for the existed emulator or install the fresh one.
Or try different emulator from BlueStack or Genymotion.